# Filter elements from dictionary of lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary named graph (directed graph), inside it has people and its friendships, giving a weight of this friendships. I'd like to remove a specific person inside this dict or change the weight of this friendship. Inside the dictionary I have sets of frozensets. The dictionary looks something like this:

```
graph={'Name1': [('Name2', 1),('Name3',3),('Name8',2)], 'Name5': [('Name1',2), ('Name3',5)], 'Name2':[('Name3',1),('Name5',4)]}
```

I would like to remove a specific friend of a specific person. For example, I'd like to remove 'Name8' from the friendships of 'Name1', resulting in this new dictionary:

```
graph={'Name1': [('Name2', 1),('Name3',3)], 'Name5': [('Name1',2), ('Name3',5)], 'Name2':[('Name3',1),('Name5',4)]}
```

Another issue is to change a weight of a friendship. For example, changing the weight of 'Name5' friendship with 'Name3' to 2, resulting in something like this:

```
graph={'Name1': [('Name2', 1),('Name3',3),('Name8',2)], 'Name5': [('Name1',2), ('Name3',2)], 'Name2':[('Name3',1),('Name5',4)]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first issue, one way would be by filtering the `'Name1'` key value from the dictionary, and merging the other keys with the dictionary unpacking operator (more on this usage [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)):

```
{**graph, **{'Name1':[(i,j) for i,j in graph['Name1'] if i != 'Name8']}}

{'Name1': [('Name2', 1), ('Name3', 3)],
 'Name5': [('Name1', 2), ('Name3', 5)],
 'Name2': [('Name3', 1), ('Name5', 4)]}
```

---

And for the second, similarly you could do:

```
{**graph, **{'Name5':[(i,j) if i != 'Name3' else (i,2) for i,j in graph['Name5']]}}

{'Name1': [('Name2', 1), ('Name3', 3), ('Name8', 2)],
 'Name5': [('Name1', 2), ('Name3', 2)],
 'Name2': [('Name3', 1), ('Name5', 4)]}
```

---

General solution for filtering with multiple conditions:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in graph.items():
    if k == 'Name1':
        for i,j in v:
            if i != 'Name8':
                d[k].append((i,j))
    elif k == 'Name5':
        for i,j in v:
            if i != 'Name3':
                d[k].append((i,2))     
            else:
                d[k].append((i,j))     
    else:
        d[k].append(v)
```